# Passing NON-POD type to Variadic function is undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

[In this document](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0073/print/), the author said

> Only a POD-type can be an argument for the ellipsis "..." while std::string is not a POD-type.

I'm understanding this as `Passing NON-POD type to Variadic function is undefined behavior`. Is it right?
Though, is he saying C/C++ standard? I tried to find it at n3242 C++ spec. But can not find.

I'd like to know I'm understanding rightly and this is a standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's specified in C++11 5.2.2/7:

> Passing a potentially-evaluated argument of class type having a non-trivial copy constructor, a non-trivial move contructor, or a non-trivial destructor, with no corresponding
>   parameter, is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics.

So it's up to each compiler whether to support it or not; portable code can't rely on any implementation defined behaviour. In older standards, it was simply undefined.

Comment: So it is **Implementation Defined** *not* **Undefined**.

Comment: @Als: It's conditionally supported; a compiler can choose to leave it undefined. So it's undefined whether or not it's defined.

Comment: Thank you, how did you find it so fast, though? I can not find, everytime I tried. Is there something secret you have?

Comment: @Benjamin: You can buy a (searchable) PDF of the standard ($30 from ANSI, or a few hundred from other organisations), or download a public draft version [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).

Comment: @Mike: yeah, I have one. Even though I have a spec, I can hardly familiar with it because it has too difficult sentences for me. It was just grumbling. Never mind :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It is implementation defined whether it is defined or not.And whatever be the case it will be well doccumented by the Implementation,So it is Implementation Defined in that sense.

Comment: @Als: Yes, that's what I meant. It's a shame I can't correct the typo in my comment.

Comment: Sorry to drudge up such an old answer, you're probably aware by now that "conditionally-supported with implementation defined semantics" does not leave the possibility of undefined behavior. (And if not, then you should be!)

Comment: From 1.4.2.2: "If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an occurrence of a construct described in this Standard as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support that construct, a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message." (So if it does not support it, it must fail compilation.)

Comment: And from 1.9.2: "Certain aspects and operations of the abstract machine are described in this International Standard as implementation-defined (for example, sizeof(int)).  These constitute the parameters of the abstract machine. Each implementation shall include documentation describing its characteristics and behavior in these respects." (And if it does support it, it must have well defined and documented behavior.)