# typeid results not matching

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid

I have function:

```
 void func(unsigned int event) {
       printf("%u %u\r\n", typeid(event), typeid(unsigned int&));
    // prints 5338164 0
       printf("%u %u\r\n", typeid(event), typeid(unsigned int));
    // prints 21525556 0
}
```

Assume this question is RTFM-related, but i reread `typeid()` man page several times and could not find an answer.
What is wrong with this code? Why `%u`'s is not equal? also why it changes first `%u` when I changed 2nd param in code.
Thanks.

Comment: `'\n'` already does a `\r\n` if the system uses CRLF line endings. Anyway, this code doesn't compile in Clang.

Comment: i assume that using \r\n is good style & portable way

Comment: `typeid(..)` returns an object of type `type_info` or something derived from it, certainly not an unsigned integer. [cppreference: `typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Comment: @SergeyEfimov, If the system uses CRLF line endings, you'll end up with `\r\r\n`. If it uses CR line endings, you'll get `\r\r`. `'\n'` is good style and portable.

Comment: @SergeyEfimov: It's portably wrong. You'll end up with a spurious `\r` on any system.

Comment: ok thanks, did not think about this. just wanted to make code portable, and if i run it on windows with \n on console it just goes Y+1. when on *nix it goes to X=1,Y=Y+1

Comment: Well, yes, because `\r` goes back to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
printf("%s %s\n", typeid(event).name(), typeid(unsigned int).name());
```

As previous replies said, the result of typeid() is opaque and cannot be printed as if it was an int. The fact that this code compiles is just a result of C's bad typing.

Comment: Yes, just looked at this structure, i think the return type is overloaded. So you mean i can't get int value descriebing type id? So the only way is comparing strings?? Hmm... Or i missed something?

Comment: `type_info` can be compared, but not printed, it has `==` and `!=`

Comment: @SergeyEfimov: If you want an int value, and you have C++11 support, use typeid(unsigned int).hash_code().

Comment: @MobyDisk - you should tell him that different types may have the same hash_code. This is dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

So [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) returns a [std::type_info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) not an *unsigned int*. This appears to compile in Visual Studio but it is not clear what the result means. This code does not compile in either `gcc` nor `clang`.

It is undefined behavior to use the wrong format specifier for `printf` so the behavior is really unpredictable. Visual Studio does not have to produce a warning for this but doing so would be help prevent problems like this. Since `std::type_info` is not a trivial class do it is implementation defined behavior to use in a variadic function, `clang` produces this warning:

```
error: cannot pass non-trivial object of type 'const std::type_info' to variadic function; expected type from format string was 'unsigned int' [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
 printf("%u %u\r\n", typeid(event), typeid(unsigned int));
         ~~
```

Using [std::type_info::name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) which returns a *const char* will give the result you expect:

```
 printf("%s %s\n", typeid(event).name(), typeid(unsigned int&).name());
```

and the result from Visual Studio:

> ```
> unsigned int unsigned int
> unsigned int unsigned int
> ```

Comment: gcc's rtti is not compatible with ms vc? i mean just standart c++ implementation of c++ rtti

Comment: @SergeyEfimov it looks like visual studio is not doing any checking with the types you pass to printf.

Comment: Interesting!  I didn't know that the behavior is undefined in C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083844