# Can't append string more than once in c++

Tags: c++, string, append

I am trying to append more strings together, when I use append once, it works fine, but after using it again it fails.

```
camName = "./XML//X";
std::string camera1 = "cam1";
camName.append(camera1);
```

This gives me string ./XML//Xcam1 and it's fine.

```
camName = "./XML//X";
std::string xml = ".xml";
camName.append(xml);
```

This also gives a good result -> ./XML//X.xml

But then I tried to do both:

```
camName = "./XML//X";
std::string camera1 = "cam1";

camName.append(camera1);
std::string xml = ".xml";

camName.append(xml);
```

I expected this to give me -> ./XML//Xcam1.xml

But instead I get something like this -> ≡┼2U_

EDIT:
This is my whole function:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

bool MyStitcher::checkCameras(string c1, string c2, string c3, string c4, string c5, string c6) {
    string camName = "./XML//X";

    if (c1 != "a") {
        camName.append(c1);
    }
    else if (c2 != "a") {
        camName.append(c2);
    }
    else if (c3 != "a") {
        camName.append(c3);
    }
    else if (c4 != "a") {
        camName.append(c4);
    }
    else if (c5 != "a") {
        camName.append(c5);
    }
    else if (c6 != "a") {
        camName.append(c6);
    }

    std::string xml = ".xml";
    camName.append(xml);

    printf("name %s\n", camName);

    if (FILE *file = fopen(camName.c_str(), "r")) {
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If one of the if statements is true, i get weird result(c1,c2,... are strings like "cam1" etc.)

Comment: you need to post your complete code, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted

Comment: Please show the declaration of `camName`.

Comment: it's just std::string camName

Comment: Your problem is that you are using printf incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on hand is an incorrect use of `printf`
As `printf` is a C-function, it has some limitations.

In this specific case, it contains C-style variadic arguments. Calling such a function with a non-POD (plain old data) is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10083844/2466431). In this case, it seems to be your compiler is reinterpret casting the `std::string`.

Because `std::string` has a [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21694302/2466431), this seems to working until you have too many characters in it.

There are 2 ways of solving this:

```
printf("name %s\n", camName.c_str());
```

This will get the `char*` from the string, which is also known by C and will work.
However, `printf` also has has a C++ variant in which it is less likely to have conversion issues: cout

```
std::cout << "name " << camName << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("name %s\n", camName);
```

should be

```
printf("name %s\n", camName.c_str());
```

Comment: Please explain why the original is incorrect, otherwise the poster will keep doing this wrong as he/she doesn't understand why it went wrong.